# Server 2003 - Default installation of SharePoint throws javascript error 'undefined' is null or not an object

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs, sharepoint

I have been handed a server that has a fresh installation of small business server 2003.

SharePoint has been installed, and it is a completely fresh copy (no changes made)

I know for a fact that everything was paid for so this isn't some dodgy copy.

When I try to click any option in any of the floating menu's in IE 8, the browser asks me if I want to debug .. Error: 'undefined' is null or not an object

for example, I got to Projects - and click on the sample project, then click delete on the floating menu that pops up and the error appears.

This is brand new, I cannot believe I am having this problem!

Has anyone come across this, is it an old problem with easy fix?

All windows updates installed - see no updates for sharepoint?

EDIT: This is WSS2 so I am going to upgrade to WSS3...
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14117
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/installing-windows-sharepoint-services-30-on-windows-server-2003/6176833

Hopefully this will resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wss2 was designed for ie6 which explains why the better browser breaks (thanks microsoft!)
upgraded to wss3 and works amazingly. will accept this as my answer when SO allows (2 days)

Comment: Did any of the doom and gloom MS suggests might happen regarding CompanyWeb actually occur?

Answer (score 0):

STOP RIGHT NOW!!!!! SBS 2003 is not the same as Server 2003. If you try a default upgrade from WSS2 you could destroy the SharePoint install.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671966(WS.10).aspx